# Multiplication Table For Python in IEP?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I Am using python 3.3 with IEP and i am trying to make a multiplication table that is nice an orderly. Everywhere i look online says it will be nice but it ends up just being 1 row and long where i want

```
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
```

the code i find is generally like this... SO whats wrong with it?

```
def main():


    i = 1
    print("-" * 50)
    while i < 11:
        n = 1
        while n <= 10:
            print("%4d" % (i * n),)
            n += 1
        print("")
        i += 1
    print("-" * 50)
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a line break after each `print`

Change 7th line to

```
print("%4d" % (i * n), end=" ")
```

Comment: Thanks that did wonders, Sorry for the dumb question just learning all this lol.

Comment: So if you know VB i have another question with no answers yet lol http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381964/reading-a-database-to-a-list-and-then-doing-something-with-the-info

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right here:

```
print("%4d" % (i * n),)
```

Each `print` call implicitly puts a line break at the end of the output, but you can change that by providing the `end` keyword argument to `print()`.

You can do something like this:

```
In [1]: def print_table(size):
   ...:     for i in range(1, size+1):
   ...:         print(''.join('{:>4d}'.format(i*j) for j in range(1, size+1)))
   ...:

In [2]: print_table(5)
   1   2   3   4   5
   2   4   6   8  10
   3   6   9  12  15
   4   8  12  16  20
   5  10  15  20  25
```